# RegEx for passing space and single quote

Tags: javascript, regex, string, regex-greedy

I'm fairly new to RegEx's and am having some issues getting my RegEx to do what I'd like it to. I'm attempting to create a RegEx that prevents any special character OTHER THAN single quote ('), dash (-), and period (.).
The RegEx needs to allow spaces, and empty strings.

What I have for now is:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-.]*$
```

What would I need to add in order to make it work for example the name "Kevin O'Leary"?

I've attempted to allow spaces by adding \s, but it broke other parts of my RegEx.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-.]*$
```

Expected: Should allow names like Kevin O'Leary
Actual: Does not allow names like Kevin O'Leary

Comment: Make sure to put the hyphen as first or last in the `[ ]`, otherwise it has a "range" meaning. Don't forget to list the quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a quote and a space to the character range:

```
^[ a-zA-Z0-9'.-]*$
```

The space can simply be a literal space in the pattern. Also, you need to have the `-` as the last symbol, because it has a special meaning in ranges.

**[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y2D3XR/1)**

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the assistance! @ruohola

Answer (score 0):

You can use `i` flag and use this expression:

```
^[a-z0-9'-.\s]+$
```

where `\x27` is `'` and `\s` is space.

```js
const regex = /^[a-z0-9'-.\s]+$/gmi;
const str = `Kevin O'Leary`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/09BU48/1/)

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified/changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/09BU48/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: `Invalid range end in character class ^[a-z0-9-<<<HERE>>>.\x27\s]+$` and, why use a byte construct in the class `\x27` ?

Comment: I'll leave editing up to the owner. To me, unless there is a need to be cryptic, byte notation is hard to read `Invalid range end in character class ^[\x09-\x0d\x1C-\x20\x61-\x7a\x30-\x39-<<<HERE>>>\x2e\x27\x85}\xa0\x{1680}\x{2000}-\x{200a}\x{2028}-\x{2029}\x{202f}\x{205f}\x{3000}]+$`